# Python JSON preserve encoding

Tags: python, json, encoding

I have a file like this:

```
aarónico
aaronita
ababol
abacá
abacería
abacero
ábaco
#more words, with no ascii chars
```

When i read and print that file to the console, it prints exactly the same, as expected, but when i do:

```
f.write(json.dumps({word: Lookup(line)}))
```

This is saved instead:

```
{"aar\u00f3nico": ["Stuff"]}
```

When i expected:

```
{"aarónico": ["Stuff"]}
```

I need to get the same when i jason.loads() it, but i don't know where or how to do the encoding or if it's needed to get it to work.

**EDIT**

This is the code that saves the data to a file:

```
with open(LEMARIO_FILE, "r") as flemario:
    with open(DATA_FILE, "w") as f:
        while True:
            word = flemario.readline().strip()
            if word == "":
                break
            print word #this is correct
            f.write(json.dumps({word: RAELookup(word)}))
            f.write("\n")
```

And this one loads the data and returns the dictionary object:

```
    with open(DATA_FILE, "r") as f:
        while True:
            new = f.readline().strip()
            if new == "":
                break
            print json.loads(new) #this is not
```

I cannot lookup the dictionaries if the keys are not the same as the saved ones.

**EDIT 2**

```
>>> import json
>>> f = open("test", "w")
>>> f.write(json.dumps({"héllö": ["stuff"]}))
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open("test", "r")
>>> print json.loads(f.read())
{u'h\xe9ll\xf6': [u'stuff']}
>>> "héllö" in {u'h\xe9ll\xf6': [u'stuff']}
False
```

Comment: You are looking at the JSON encoding of a unicode character. *That is normal*. This is fully compliant [RFC 4627 JSON](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) (see section 2.5 on string values).

Comment: Json is saving data correctly. Unicode strings are converted to the format you have presented.

Comment: But when i load it again, it doesen convert back as it was before.

Comment: @gcq: Are you certain that you are not looking at the Python string literal representation?

Comment: @gcq After loading again, try to write to a file and check. It should be the same.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i don't know what you mean, but i only want to get from json.loads() what i saved to json.dumps()

Comment: `>>> print u'h\xe9ll\xf6'` gives `héllö`. You are looking at the *python string literal representation*. Your code is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *normal* and valid JSON behaviour. The `\uxxxx` escape is *also* used by Python, so make sure you don't confuse python literal representations with the contents of the string.

Demo in Python 3.3:

```
>>> import json
>>> print('aar\u00f3nico')
aarónico
>>> print(json.dumps('aar\u00f3nico'))
"aar\u00f3nico"
>>> print(json.loads(json.dumps('aar\u00f3nico')))
aarónico
```

In python 2.7:

```
>>> import json
>>> print u'aar\u00f3nico'
aarónico
>>> print(json.dumps(u'aar\u00f3nico'))
"aar\u00f3nico"
>>> print(json.loads(json.dumps(u'aar\u00f3nico')))
aarónico
```

When reading and writing from and to files, and when specifying just raw byte strings (and `"héllö"` is a raw byte string) then you are *not* dealing with Unicode data. You need to learn about the differences between encoded and Unicode data first. I **strongly** recommend you read at least 2 of the following 3 articles:

- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky

You were lucky with your `"héllö"` python raw byte string representation, Python managed to decode it automatically for you. The value read back from the file is perfectly normal and correct:

```
>>> print u'h\xe9ll\xf6'
héllö
```

Comment: @gcq: You are opening a file without specifying the encoding. Is this Python 2 or 3, do you *know* what encoding is used for the files?

Comment: @gcq: You need to give us *much more detail* as to what you see when you do this (use `repr()` on the input and output, give us a Python session like in my answer for example, so we can help you debug).

Comment: @Martjin is python 2 and no, i don't know the encoding used in this file, but never had problems before writing and reading non ascii chars from files.

Comment: @gcq: Which is what I'd ask you to do anyway. :-) You can read bytes from files just fine, you just will *not* get `\uxxxx` unicode character escapes that way.

Comment: @Martijin then what can i do to retrieve the json from the file? I cannot use json.dump() and .load() becouse in the file every line is one json object. To do that i would need to load about 88000 dictionaries in memory, and i don't want to do that.

Comment: @gcq: When reading non-ASCII data from a file (that is not JSON), you need to decode that data to Unicode. For files holding JSON, the `loads()` function takes care of decoding provided it was written as UTF-8 (which `dumps()` does by default).

Comment: you could use the same code for Python 2 and 3.3 e.g., `print(u"aar\u00f3nico")`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: There are still enough 3.2 installations out there that I am wary of using `u''` in Python 3 code.